# Duplicated Rows No Longer Recognized As Duplicates After read_csv() Is Used

Tags: r, duplicates, readr

I have a historical file for a project. If we call this data frame A, say it is 5000 rows by 20 columns, I need to constantly be appending A with new records as they come in.

If I want to test that I'm removing duplicates, my test is:

```
A <- rbind(A, A) #These are the exact same file. This is now 10,000 x 20

A <- dplyr::filter(A, !duplicated(A)) #using the dplyr package, this is now 5,000 x 20
```

Keep in mind, the above works as it should. It removes all duplicates. However, when I want to test that this works I save the file, then read it in again and rbind once more:

```
readr::write_csv(A, "path/A_saved") #Saving the historical file A

A_import <- readr::read_csv("A_saved") #Loading in the historical file I just saved to my computer

A <- rbind(A, A_import) #Again, these are still the exact same file, same dimension with the same records, each with a duplicate row. This is now 10,000 by 20

A <- dplyr::filter(A, !duplicated(A)) #Same as above, BUT this is now 6,000 x 20
```

It is removing the majority of duplicates. However, it does not remove all the duplicates. Upon inspection, the 1,000 rows that should have been removed are still exact duplicates of other rows.

What is happening when I use read_csv() and the duplicated() function in this instance? I searched far and wide for a similar issue and could not find a solution.

I have used the unique() function as opposed to duplicated() and the problem persists. When I read in the exact same data frame, rbind() the data frame object with its read_csv() version, then try to filter() duplicates, not all duplicates are filtered.

duplicated() is not recognizing all rows as proper duplicates.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: DO you have any columns with decimals (float)?  Perhaps then `round`ing the corresponding columns and checking for duplicates solves

Comment: Just tried rounding every numeric column to 4 digits, reran my test and the same result occurs. There are ~6,000 rows remaining still, where 1,000 of them are duplicated.

Comment: Without a small reproducible example, it is difficult to know why you are getting this.  Do you have the same `str` for both the datasets?  Any 'Date' column which converts to integers while writing etc? Or having leading/lagging spaces in one of the datasets in any column?

Comment: It appears to have been all or most of these issues: A change in class() of some columns when reading/writing, a rounding issue and/or a whitespace issue. For good measure I implemented fixes for all of these, and it appears to be working now! Thank you so much for the suggestions!! Been working on this for a week now. Thank you!! Lessons learned!!